# Automation of Flash based application using UFT

Tags: flash, flex3, hp-uft

I am trying to automate a Flash based application using UFT 12.02. Selecting the Flex Add-in but still all the objects are just getting recognised as webelements only.

Can anyone please guide me on how to make UFT recognize flash based objects in my application to support automation?

Comment: UFT and Flash do not work well together.  In most cases where I've needed to have UFT interact with Flash objects such as menu items on a web page, I've found it simpler to trigger the intended effect rather than try to use the object...

Comment: I am guessing you have followed **prerequisites** section from [**this**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/z_Ch_AddinFlex.htm) page.

Comment: Are you sure your application is a Flex application and not just a native Flash app?  I ask respectfully, in this day and age I mostly see SDev running into these sort of issues. :D

Comment: Flash has ALWAYS been hard to test, but it's been close to impossible to test Flash applications in certain environments like Chrome these days unless your roll back to an older version that supported the Debug player. Verify that the test server is using the Debug version of Flash.  Is this a browser based test?  If you have done all the step mentioned in the post that ManishChristian mentioned then you might want to investigate if you have Flash sandbox issues, and/or crossdomain.xml woes. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html